# Finding initial amount of ammonia using equilibrium constant and amount of nitrogen gas

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, equilibrium, concentration

#### Question

> When an amount ammonia is added at $\pu{600 K}$ in a $\pu{1 L}$ container the following reaction takes place:
>
> $$\ce{N2(g) + 3 H2(g) <=> 2 NH3(g)}$$
>
> The equilibrium constant $K_c = 4.20$ at $\pu{600 K}.$
>
> At equilibrium, it is known that $\pu{0.200 mol}$ of $\ce{N2}$ gas exist in the container. What amount of ammonia was added at the start of the reaction? Choose from the answers below:
>
> $\pu{0.826 mol};$ $\pu{0.482 mol};$ $\pu{1.226 mol};$ $\pu{0.400 mol};$ $\pu{0.800 mol}.$

#### My attempt

I created an ICE table, but I think it's wrong:

$$
\begin{array}{lccc}
\ce{&N2(g) &+ &3 H2(g) &<=> &2 NH3(g)} \\
\text{I} & 0 && 0 && y \\
\text{C} & +x && +3x && -4x \\
\text{E} & 0.2 && 0.6 && y-0.8 \\
\end{array}
$$

$$K_c = \frac{(y - 0.8)^2}{0.200\times 0.6^3}$$

Solving the equation with Maple gives me none of the answers above. I must have messed up on the table. Can anyone tell me where I messed up?

Comment: The method is ok, but you made a slip, the term for ammonia is not -4x, correct this and you will get one of the answers. In an exam you can get the answer easily with a hand calculator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the volume is given and it's a constant, the initial amount of ammonia $n_0(\ce{NH3})$ can be found from its initial concentration $c_0(\ce{NH3}):$

$$n_0(\ce{NH3}) = c_0(\ce{NH3})\times V\tag{1}$$

To find $c_0(\ce{NH3}),$ an ICE table might indeed come in handy; however, yours needs corrections.
First, I suggest to rewrite it according to the process occurring in the system, namely dissociation of ammonia:

$$
\begin{array}{lccc}
\ce{&2 NH3(g) &<=> &N2(g) &+ &3 H2(g)} \\
\text{I} & c_0 && 0 && 0 \\
\text{C} & -2x && +x && +3x \\
\text{E} & c_0 - 2x && x && 3x \\
\end{array}
$$

Second, note that the provided equilibrium constant $K_c$ is given for the *synthesis* of ammonia, hence in our case a reciprocal value is relevant:

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{K_c} &= \frac{[\ce{N2}][\ce{H2}]^3}{[\ce{NH3}]^2}\tag{2.1}\\
\frac{1}{K_c} &= \frac{x (3x)^3}{(c_o - 2x)^2}\tag{2.2}\\
\frac{1}{K_c} &= \frac{27x^4}{(c_o - 2x)^2}\tag{2.3}\\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{K_c}} &= \frac{3\sqrt{3}x^2}{c_o - 2x}\tag{2.4}
\end{align}
$$

$$c_0 = 3\sqrt{3K_c}x^2 + 2x\tag{3}$$

At the equilibrium there is $\pu{0.200 mol}$ of nitrogen in the $\pu{1 L}$ vessel, so $x = \pu{0.200 mol L-1},$ and the initial amount of ammonia can be found as follows:

$$
\begin{align}
n_0(\ce{NH3}) &= (3\sqrt{3K_c}x^2 + 2x) × V\\
  &= (3\sqrt{3\times 4.20}\times (\pu{0.200 mol L-1})^2 + 2\times \pu{0.200 mol L-1})\times \pu{1 L} \\
  &= \pu{0.826 mol}\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$